# What is the difference between Array.from({length: 5}) and Array(5).fill(undefined)?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between:

```
Array.from({length: 5})
```

and

```
Array(5).fill(undefined)
```

I can see that both methods are creating an array with `undefined` values.

But I don't understand their difference.

Comment: There is no difference. The output of both expressions is the same.

Comment: `.from` creates a new array that's sized depending on the `length` property of the object passed in which is usually an Array like object, but as in your example does not have to be - this leaves all elements at the default (`undefined`).  Array(5) creates a new array with length 5 and then assigns each element, in your example to `undefined`.  2nd version is probably slower since the `.fill` is pointless (`Array(5)` would do the same).  End result is the same

Comment: @Tibrogargan The fill is not pointless. It changes it from an array with five empty slots to an array with five non-empty slots all holding the value `undefined`.

Comment: @Paulpro and yet, `typeof (Array(5)[0])` remains `"undefined"`

Comment: @TylerRoper depends how you iterate over it, doesn't it?

Comment: @Tibrogaran, of course it remains `"undefined"`, accessing an empty slot in an array evaluates to `undefined`; but it changes E.G. `1 in Array(5)` from `false` to `1 in Array(5).fill(undefined) === true`, and changes whether or not the slots will be visited in iteration with Array#map or Array#forEach, amongst others. It's definitely not pointless.

Comment: @TylerRoper sure it is.  both `for (var i of Array(5)`and `for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` work.  `(var in)` doesn't, because the indexes themselves don't exist.  Neither I assume would things like `Object.keys`

Comment: @TylerRoper So yes, in a nitpicky, pedantic way they are different.  It's an interesting question as to whether there would ever be a non-contrived situation where it would make a difference

Comment: @TylerRoper already said they are different.  What's I'm saying is that the set of ciscumstances in which it might make a difference and that are not contrived is very small.

Comment: @Tibrogargan—it makes a difference with the newer iterative methods like *forEach* that don't visit non–existent properties. `Array(5).forEach(x => console.log(x))` doesn't print anything.

Comment: @RobG Yes, I know.  Again, there doesn't seem to be a whole lot of situations where you might need to do that.  Asynchronous poll based initialization of a collection where position was important perhaps - but still hard to see how that's not contrived.

Comment: @TylerRoper Granted, but requiring them to do something meaningful for `undefined` is.  You're deliberately creating a dense array with undefined elements.  This might be meaningful for initialization but it's tough coming up with a reason for it otherwise - maybe there's some very clever use cases.

Answer (score 1):

They have different use cases. `Array.from` is useful, for example, with some DOM methods that return an array-like object, but none of the array methods. Primarily it's more for converting Array-like things to an `Array`.

```js
const children = document.getElementById('container').children;
console.log(children);

const childrenArray = Array.from(children);
console.log(childrenArray)
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>Block 1</div>
  <div>Block 2</div>
  <div>Block 3</div>
  <div>Block 4</div>
</div>
```

`Array.fill` is more straightforward where you have some array of known size and want to fill it with a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

Array().`from`()  returns the undefined values as it has not specified the specific values for an array indices.

The fact with `Array(5).fill(<some_value>)` is obvious. Because it always fills the same value up to the length of the array (In your case it's undefined)